# Is it possible to manipulate filtered data and group them together to create a new category in excel?

Tags: excel, filter, slice, group

I am working on crime data in excel and I want to group different crimes description under one category. For example, theft, burglary, robbery in one group and etc.

After filtering them, is it possible to change the crime description of those rows so I can use them as one category?

Comment: please provide some example to understand it better